# Querying stream table for user's own posts returns photo tags by others

Tags: facebook-fql

I am querying the stream table to retrieve everything that the logged in user has posted recently. I am using the following query:

SELECT source_id, actor_id, app_id, post_id, created_time, message, likes, attachment 
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id = XXXXX
AND actor_id = XXXXX

The problem is that the response includes entries for when other users have tagged the logged in user in photos, which I don't consider to be a post from the logged in user him/herself.

I have looked at other fields in the stream table such as taget_id and viewer_id but cannot find a way to limit the results.

Can anyone help me to excludes these tag posts or identify in the returned data which entries are tagged photos (or other things that can be tagged)?

Thank you in advance.

// Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish what you're trying to do by looping over the entries, and if the attachment is a photo or video, checking to see if the owner id is the same as the user id. If it's a different user id, then you know they didn't post it and they were just tagged in the photo.

Comment: Thank you - that works! Even though it would have been nicer to exclude those posts by FQL arguments.